# Outlook export to .pst file: You don't have appropriate permission to perform this operation

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, export, pst

When I try to export my e-mails from Outlook into a `.pst` file, I get the following error:

```
You don't have appropriate permission to perform this operation.
```

I have full access permissions to the folder where I try to create the `.pst` file. I don't try to update an existing `.pst` file, but to create a new one instead. I'm using a domain user account on a domain computer. How can I successfully export my e-mails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the registry value `HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\pst\pstdisablegrow`, with the following command in PowerShell, for example:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\pst -Name pstdisablegrow | Select-Object -ExpandProperty pstdisablegrow
```

If it returns `1`, close Outlook and set the value to `0`. You don't need administrative privileges for this:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\pst -Name pstdisablegrow -Value 0
```

After that, open Outlook again and you should be able to export your e-mails successfully.

If you are using another Outlook version than 2016, change the value `16.0` in the path according to the following table:

| Outlook Version | Version Number |
| --- | --- |
| Outlook 2007 | 12.0 |
| Outlook 2010 | 14.0 |
| Outlook 2013 | 15.0 |
| Outlook 2016 and Office 365 | 16.0 |
| Outlook 2019 | 19.0 |

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are many influencing factors for this problem. Please try troubleshooting according to the following steps:

1.First, considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you try to ***start outlook in safe mode***(win+R>type: outlook /safe) to check whether it works normally. If it can run normally in safe mode, you need to [disable all the add ins and check which add ins cause it one by one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/i-can-t-start-microsoft-outlook-or-receive-the-error-cannot-start-microsoft-office-outlook-cannot-open-the-outlook-window-d1f69da6-b333-4650-97bf-4d77bd7abb85?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#:%7E:text=Start%20Outlook%20in%20safe%20mode%20and%20disable%20add%2Dins).

2.If this is still the issue in safe mode, it is suggested that you could try to ***create a new profile***(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

3.If it still doesn't work after rebuilding the profile, you can try the method of ***modifying the registry key*** you mentioned.
(It should be noted that if you modify the registry by mistake, serious problems may occur. Please [back up the registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692) before operation.)

4.If none of the above is valid, considering that it would also be affected when the outlook program itself is damaged. It is recommended that you try to ***[fix the Office application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)***.

Hope the above help!

Comment: The problem is still reproducible, when I change the registry value back to `1`. And I actually keep it on `1`, as it was set like that before. But to successfully export all objects of my account, I have to set it to `0`. It even sounds reasonable to me that this value has to be `0` for this purpose, because otherwise a `.pst` file would not be allowed to grow, which has to happen for an export. I don't know the default value though, may be my company set it to `1` for whatever reason.

Comment: Actually, the PSTDisableGrow value of 1 is used to prevent users from adding new data or content to an existing .pst file.(for more information about it, please refer to: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/outlook-issues/control-pst-use#:~:text=case%20problems%20occur.-,Prevent%20users%20from%20adding%20new%20data%20or%20content%20to%20an%20existing%20.pst%20file,-To%20prevent%20users) Anyway, it's good that this works for you. If this is not what you ultimately want, It's suggested that you could try some of the other methods I mentioned.